# How is SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation supposed to work with Bias

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, dst

I have a piece of code which is attempting to disable daylight savings time on Windows (Embedded 7) but with a strange way (I think) of going about it. Unfortunately the code was written by someone else who has long since gone, and I'm not sure what they were trying to do.

```
        DynamicTimeZoneInformation timeZoneInfo;
        GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(out timeZoneInfo);
        timeZoneInfo.DisableDynamicDaylightTime();

        // Disable windows daylight saving time.
        DateTimeOffset ptime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        bool enabled = SecurityApi.EnablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");
        bool changed = SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(ref timeZoneInfo);
        bool disabled = SecurityApi.DisablePrivilege("SeTimeZonePrivilege");
        TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
```

and...

```
      public void DisableDynamicDaylightTime()
        {
            this.DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled = true;
            this.Bias = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Year = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Month = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Day = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Hour = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Minute = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Second = 0;
            this.StandardDate.Milliseconds = 0;
            this.StandardDate.DayOfWeek = 0;
            this.StandardBias = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Year = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Month = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Day = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Hour = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Minute = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Second = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.Milliseconds = 0;
            this.DaylightDate.DayOfWeek = 0;
            this.DaylightBias = 0;
        }
```

Now, there is code later on that is supposed to change the clock back to the local timezone by adding the offset to the Utc Time, but that's not really where my problem is.

My question is this. Let's say I set the Timezone (through Windows) to Baghdad, which is UTC+3:00. The current time 11:00. When I get the timezone information, this has a `Bias` of -180 and a `StandardBias` of -60. The code above sets both Biases to 0, and then I call `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation()`. So as expected, the Time is set back to 08:00 (because the Bias is now 0).

However, when it gets to `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`, it sets the UTC time (i.e. `DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime`) to 05:00 ! 3 hours back again. I would have expected the UTC time and the currently displayed system time to be the same now because the Bias is 0.

Is this the expected behaviour of `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation()`? It seems extra strange because I have another project which has identical code for this part but doesn't do this - it behaves as I expected in the previous paragraph. (So the UTC time would remain at 08:00)

The only difference I can see between that one and this is that uses .Net Framework v3.5 whereas this one is v4.0

Comment: Hi.  This is the type of question that would benefit from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code above isn't complete or verifiable.  Could you please edit your question to make it so?  I can sorta guess at what might have been going on in your former developer's mind, but in general it's quite strange to be seeing functions related to `DynamicTimeZoneInformation` (from the Win32 API) mixed with your .NET code.  You should be sure to include your PInvoke calls in your MCVE.

Comment: Then again, it might be a better plan to reassess what is trying to be achieved with this code in the first place.  There's probably a better way that doesn't involve changing the system time zone.  It's quite a hack to change a system-wide setting for an individual app's needs.  Can you imagine if multiple apps were trying to change the system time zone at the same time?!

Comment: Also, note that `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData` only clears what .NET has read the system time zone to be, from the static variables held internally in .NET components.  This affects things like `TimeZoneInfo.Local` and `DateTime.Now`.  It cannot affect the system time or system time zone setting at all, nor would it affect `DateTime.UtcNow`.  So when you say "it sets the UTC time to 05:00" - it cannot.

Comment: @MattJohnson - I will try to come up with an MCVE - however I have to say that `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` is changing the `DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime`. Not sure if this changes your above statement but I'll edit my question to reflect.

Comment: That's the same as `DateTime.UtcNow`, just going through two extra conversions.